# How can I insert data into different tables using the same controller?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am using Laravel (coming from CodeIgniter) and I am struggling on getting a table that contains a foreign key populated.

I have two tables: `People` & `Friends`

My `People` table has fields like "First Name", "Last Name" etc.

At the bottom of my form, I can add a friend. Each friend can have a "First Name", "Last Name" etc. I can add as many friends as I like.

I am successfully populating my `People` table, then loop through my friends fields to populate my `Friends` table.

**MyController.php**

```
if ($person->save()) {  // Save the primary record.

    // check if there are any friends to save.
    $friendsArray = array_filter($input['friend']);

    if (empty($friendsArray)) {
        // No friends to insert.
    } else {
        $friend = new Friend();

        $friend->person_id = $person->id;
        $friend->friend_data = json_encode(array('friend' => $input['friend']));

        $friend->save();
    }
}
```

If I log out $friend, I am seeing everything correctly. For example,

```
[attributes:protected] => Array
    (
        [person_id] => 4
        [friend_data] => {"friend":{"firstName":"Tyler","lastName":"Durden","address":"12345 Street","city":"My City","state":"CA","zip":"12345"}}
    )
```

It's just not getting inserted into my `Friend` table. I'm not getting any errors so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

Here is what my migration looks like to create my `Friends` table.

```
...
Schema::create('friends', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('person_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('person_id')->references('id')->on('people');
    $table->text('friend_data');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**EDIT 2**

After going line by line, I am seeing this in my network tab:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#039;myapplication.friend&#039; doesn&#039;t exist
```

So that tells me I have a spelling problem somewhere. The system is looking for `friend` when it should be `friends`.

**EDIT 3**

Here is what my friend model looks like:

Friend

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Friend extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Friend model please?

Comment: Hi @EduardoPacios - I've updated my question. I'm also very puzzled as to how my empty model(s) even work. None of them have any properties. Using CodeIgniter, I would usually have some sort of structure in there.

I am using `php artisan make:model Friend` to create the model.

Comment: thanks. can you add a protected property named $table and assign it the name of the table? like protected $table = 'friends';

Comment: Thanks for updating the question! Eloquent maps your table's fields automatically. You don't need to set them up. In the model you set your relationships (for example between friend and people). You can also put getters and setters if you want to modify the output/input in your model.

Comment: Wow, this really shows just how new I am to Laravel. Setting the protected var in my friend model worked. I really don't quite understand how though. Since I am declaring the table in my migration file correctly... 

Thank you very much for your suggestions. If you set it as the answer, I'll check it.

Comment: I added the answer. Yeah, I'm not sure why it doesn't recognise your table's name automatically! I didn't have that problem. Anyway, take a look to https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent , to get a better idea of Eloquent's capabilities (fillable fields, appends, eager loading, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses lots of conventions. One of them is that the model's name should be the singular of the table's name. For your friends table, the model should be Friend. In case you prefer to use your own naming, you can set the table in the model like this:

```
protected $table = 'friends';
```

Your naming seems correct, I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help & insight!